# CLIPS rule unmatch(don't fire) after retract

Tags: clips

i have a project in clips with three modules, at the end of the second module i ask to user if he want to retract one of the previous answer, if he retract one of the answer of the second module, i need to retract all the answers of the second module and re-ask again. After i retract all the answers of the second module, i expect that this rule is activated

```
(defrule SECONDMODULE::domanda-esperto
   (declare (salience ?*highest-priority*))
      (livello-utente (livello esperto)) ;;assert in FIRSTMODULE and not retract
      =>
      (something)
      )
```

But this rule is never activeted and it not apper in the AGENDA also if the facts that match the LHS is present in the fact list.

Sorry for my bad english.

EDIT.
@Gary First of all i ask 5 question to user, that are this:

```
(defrule starting-rule
 (declare (salience ?*highest-priority*) (auto-focus TRUE))
  => 
 (printout t "***Inizio***" crlf)
 (focus PROFILO)
 (set-strategy random))

(defrule PROFILO::chiedi-se-possiede-auto 
 (not (domanda (nome possiede-auto) (domanda ?) (risposta ?)))
 =>
 (bind ?risposta (si-o-no "L'auto e' tua? "))
 (assert (domanda (nome possiede-auto) (domanda "L'auto e' tua? ") (risposta ?risposta)))
 )

(defrule PROFILO::frequenza-utilizzo-auto
 (not(domanda (nome frequenza-utilizzo-auto) (domanda ?) (risposta ?)))
 =>
 (bind ?risposta (risposte-range "Quante volte a settimana in media utilizzi l'auto? " 0 1-2 3-5 5-7 ))
 (assert (domanda (nome frequenza-utilizzo-auto) (domanda "Quante volte a settimana in media utilizzi l'auto? " ) (risposta ?risposta)))
)

(defrule PROFILO::conoscenza-meccanica-auto
 (not (domanda (nome conoscenza-meccanica-auto) (domanda ?) (risposta ?)))
=>
(bind ?risposta (risposte-range "Quanto ti consideri esperto della meccanica dell'auto?" 0 1 2 3 4 5))
(assert (domanda (nome conoscenza-meccanica-auto) (domanda "Quanto ti consideri esperto della meccanica dell'auto?") (risposta ?risposta)))
)

(defrule PROFILO::kit-riparazione-rapida
 (not (domanda (nome kit-riparazione-rapida) (domanda ?) (risposta ?)))
=>
(bind ?risposta (si-o-no "Possiedi un kit di riparazione rapida?"))
(assert (domanda (nome kit-riparazione-rapida) (domanda "Possiedi un kit di riparazione rapida?") (risposta ?risposta)))
)

(defrule PROFILO::anni-possesso-patente
 (not(domanda (nome anni-possesso-patente) (domanda ?) (risposta ?)))
 =>
 (bind ?risposta (risposte-range "Da quanti anni possiedi la patente? " <1 1-5 >5 ))
 (assert (domanda (nome anni-possesso-patente) (domanda "Da quanti anni possiedi la patente? ") (risposta ?risposta)))
)
```

After this i fire a rule that in according with the user asnwers delineate the profile of the user

```
(defrule PROFILO::livello-utente 
 ?a<-(domanda (nome possiede-auto) (domanda ?) (risposta ?))
 ?b<-(domanda (nome anni-possesso-patente) (domanda ?) (risposta ?))
 ?c<-(domanda (nome conoscenza-meccanica-auto) (domanda ?) (risposta ?))
 ?d<-(domanda (nome kit-riparazione-rapida) (domanda ?) (risposta ?))
 ?e<-(domanda (nome frequenza-utilizzo-auto) (domanda ?) (risposta ?))
 =>

 (switch (fact-slot-value ?a risposta)
  (case TRUE then (bind ?*punteggio* (+ ?*punteggio* 1)))
 )
 (switch (fact-slot-value ?d risposta)
  (case TRUE then (bind ?*punteggio* (+ ?*punteggio* 1)))
 )
 (switch  (fact-slot-value ?b risposta)
  (case <1 then (bind ?*punteggio* (+ ?*punteggio* 1)))
  (case 1-5 then (bind ?*punteggio* (+ ?*punteggio* 2)))
  (case >5 then (bind ?*punteggio* (+ ?*punteggio* 3)))
 )
 (switch (fact-slot-value ?c risposta)
  (case 1 then (bind ?*punteggio* (+ ?*punteggio* 1)))
  (case 2 then (bind ?*punteggio* (+ ?*punteggio* 2)))
  (case 3 then (bind ?*punteggio* (+ ?*punteggio* 3)))
  (case 4 then (bind ?*punteggio* (+ ?*punteggio* 4)))
  (case 5 then (bind ?*punteggio* (+ ?*punteggio* 5)))
 )
 (switch (fact-slot-value ?e risposta) 
  (case 1-2 then (bind ?*punteggio* (+ ?*punteggio* 1)))
  (case 3-5 then (bind ?*punteggio* (+ ?*punteggio* 2)))
  (case 5-7 then (bind ?*punteggio* (+ ?*punteggio* 3)))
 )
 (bind ?f ?*punteggio*)
 (if (> ?f 9) then (assert (livello-utente (livello esperto))))
 (if (< ?f 6) then (assert (livello-utente (livello principiante))))
 (if (and (> ?f 5) (< ?f 10)) then (assert (livello-utente(livello medio))))

)
```

After that i go in the second module where one of this two rule ia actived in according with the profile of the user determinate in the fist module

```
(defrule DIAGNOSI::domanda-esperto
  (declare (salience ?*highest-priority*))
  (livello-utente (livello esperto))
  =>
  (bind ?risposta (risposte-range "In quale tra le seguenti aree e' presente il problema?" Olio-motore Olio-freni Acqua Carburante Altro))
  (assert (domanda (nome area-problema)  (domanda "In quale tra le seguenti aree e' presente il problema?") (risposta ?risposta)))
  )

(defrule DIAGNOSI::domanda-medio
  (declare (salience ?*highest-priority*))
  (livello-utente (livello medio))
  =>
  (bind ?risposta (si-o-no "Sapresti indicare l'area di provenienza del problema tra le seguenti: Olio motore, Olio freni, Acqua, Carburante, Altro?"))
  (assert (domanda  (nome domanda-area-problema) (domanda "Sapresti indicare l'area di provenienza del problema tra le seguenti: Olio motore, Olio freni, Acqua, Carburante, Altro?") (risposta ?risposta)))
  (if (eq ?risposta TRUE)
    then (bind ?risposta (risposte-range "In quale tra le seguenti aree e' presente il problema?" Olio-motore Olio-freni Acqua Carburante Altro))
          (assert (domanda  (nome area-problema) (domanda "In quale tra le seguenti aree e' presente il problema?") (risposta ?risposta)))
  )
```

After this there is a series of other question that i do to user. After that i ask if he want to retract one of this, and if he chooseone of the two (domanda-medio, domanda-esperto) i have to retract all the answers of the second module. After i retract all the answers of the second module, this two rule is never activeted and it not apper in the AGENDA also if the facts that match the LHS is present in the fact list (livello-utente (livello ?))

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example of the issue.

Comment: @GaryRiley ok i try, edit first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GaryRiley ok i don't know why but adding `

```
(not (diagnosi (nome ?)))`
```

to the two rule it work.